# Find formula for the most distant value from a mean

Tags: vector-spaces, average

I have a set of values and i need to find the most distant value from the mean of those values:
Let's say the values are those:

```
    [3,2,5,4,1]
    Mean = 3

The most distant value would be 5 but how can i express this in a formula?
```

Comment: The most distant value is either the maximum or minimum value or both.

Comment: What a *formula* is, depends on the language. You just expressed it in a formula in the title.

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "formula". As @PeterForeman comments, you will need to find the maximum and minimum values in the list and then the maximum of the two distances to the mean. Is this for a computer program?

Comment: I need the maximum value

Comment: Not sure there is a simple formula. If you use a computer programming language, there might be some functions that provide this (I know how to do it in python). By the way, in your data, 1 is also the farthest from the mean

Comment: I need the value which is the smallest if you substract it from the mean

Comment: It is for a computer program..Basically i need to find the value which is the most different or distant from the mean..What are my best options?

Comment: Keep four values, $U, L, m, n$, the maximum, the minimum, the mean of the values read so far, and the number of elements read so far. You will start with $U=L=m=$ the first element in the list, and $n=1$. Then at each step read the next value $a$ and update $m\leftarrow (nm+a)/(n+1)$, $n\leftarrow n+1$, $U\leftarrow \max(U,a)$, and $L\leftarrow \min(L,a)$. At the end the result is $L$ or $U$, whichever makes $m-L$ or $U-m$ largest.

Comment: In your example, why is 5 more distant from the mean than 1 is?  They both differ from the mean by 2.

Comment: Sorry about that both the values differ from the mean by 2

Comment: @logarithm Keep a running sum of the total and calculate the mean at the end of the loop rather than updating the mean each time. Post your comment as pseudocode  in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values are denoted $v_i$ and the mean $\overline v$,

$$v_{\text{argmax}_i|v_i-\overline v|}$$